# Stay on Tab after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, html, reload

I'm using the following jquery for my tabs:

```
<SCRIPT>
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
            var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

            // Show/Hide Tabs
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

            // Change/remove current tab to active
                  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

And in the body:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab1">My Submissions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        Info 1
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        Info 2
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        Info 3
    </div>
</div>
```

when I reload my page it resets to tab1 where as I want it to stay on the current tab I'm viewing for example `tab2` or `tab3`

how would I accomplish this?

Comment: You'd have to either change the url somehow (using hash or other techniques) when the tab is clicked, so when it reloads you know where they are. Or use cookies / local storage etc to store the selected state of the tab. The web is stateless so a refresh has no knowledge of the previous state. You need to record that client or server side.

Comment: I thought of the URL, but i'm not entirely sure how to update it upon click..i'm pretty much a nooby when it comes to javescript...would you be able to help me further?

Comment: Note the url change may go into history so when you click back it would flick tabs, that may be a good thing, perhaps not. window.location.hash  = "tab1"; will set the url to http://blah.com#tab1. You can use the same code to retrieve it: var currentTab = window.location.href - you would run that onload then programmatically select the tab.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I've managed to update the url when click each tab, but stuck on the second part - "run that onload then programmatically select the tab"

Comment: Hi Shaun, I'm really struggling to put a script together (noob) are you able to help? I'm not sure how to get the url/#tab2 and load the relevant tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can store current tab in localStorage.

```
<SCRIPT>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
if (window.localStorage){
    var currentTab = localStorage.getItem("currentTab");
    currentTab && $(".tabs .tab-links a[href='" + currentTab + "']").click();
}
jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
localStorage && localStorage.setItem("currentTab",currentAttrValue);
// Show/Hide Tabs
jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

// Change/remove current tab to active
      jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Shreyas, Unfortunately that script didn't work, still reverts to tab1 upon reload.